# Finding elements in ListView with Appium v.1.2.0

Tags: android, appium

```
WebElement list = explicitWaitForElement(driver, By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[1]"));
List<WebElement> weekObjectList = list.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout"));
```

The above code is not working for me. Looks like there are some issues with Appium v1.2.0. Let me know if we have any workaround.

Comment: When you say not working... what is the issue? Can you provide logs from the Appium Server?

Answer (score 1):

Please Try with the following:

```
List<WebElement> weekObjectList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[1]//android.widget.RelativeLayout"));
```

Comment: This xpath is invalid. It should be `//android.widget.ListView[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout`

Comment: This Xpath is correct. Are you confused of // and /, if so please clarify what actually these two mean?

Comment: `//` means "anywhere in the xml" and `/` means below the current/root node. [Here's the documentation on xpaths](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Then whats wrong with - //android.widget.ListView[1]//android.widget.RelativeLayout  ?

/android.widget.RelativeLayout- immediate child node
//android.widget.RelativeLayout - immediate or anywhere in the section of the parent node  (also applicable if it is the immediate child of android.widget.ListView[1])

Comment: So [here's the example](http://pastebin.com/CzFrmS1N): If you use `//classA//classB` you will get all elements of classB, regardless of how far below classA they are. (Grandchildren, etc). If you use `//classA/classB` you will get all elements of classB that are **ONLY** directly below classA (so, only children)

Comment: Thank you for understanding it . 
My question -  whats wrong with - //android.widget.ListView[1]//android.widget.RelativeLayout ? Why it is invalid?

Comment: It's not invalid, it just gets all `android.widget.RelativeLayout`s under the ListView, not just the direct children of that ListView.

Comment: Anyways now you have the idea on these two stuffs, you can implement any of them according to your requirement.